# Copy file into string in C

Tags: c, popen, fgets

I am trying to read memory information into a string in c, and I'm having a bit of trouble.  Here is what I currently have.

```
FILE * fpipe;
long length;
char * command = "free";
fpipe = (FILE*) popen(command, "r")));

fseek(fpipe, 0, SEEK_END);
length = ftell(fpipe);
fseek(fpipe, 0, SEEK_SET);
bufer = (char*) malloc(length);

char line[128];
if(fpipe)
{
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fpipe))
    {
        strcat(buffer, line);
    }
}
```

I am able to print line, but not add it to buffer.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think `char * line[128];` should be `char line[128];`

Comment: You are correct, I wrote it incorrectly from  my code. Edited now.

Comment: What do you mean by "not add it to buffer"? How did you create, allocate and *initialize* `buffer`? How do you know the size of the length of the data you read? You can't seek from a pipe (which is what `popen` uses behind the scenes). Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: You managed to implement [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter's_algorithm) perfectly. (and that isn't a good thing, fyi).

Comment: I have updated my code, hopefully it is more helpful now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification to my previous comment, and the problem with your code now that we can see it: If you have a pipe, you can only seek *forward*, not backwards. Once you seeked to the end, you can no longer go back and all the data is lost.

Instead you need to dynamically allocate and [*reallocate*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) the buffer each iteration.

Comment: Thanks so much, was able to get this to work.  Thank you for the explanation as well!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading binary data from the file. Therefore, you cannot treat it as a null terminated string.

Use `memcpy()` instead of strcat.

Comment: Nothing in the question says that the data is binary, quite the opposite if the file is opened using `popen` with a command that outputs text.

Comment: No, the OP uses the `popen` function to read the *output* from the command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{

char *command="ls -ltr";
FILE* fp;
char line[128];
char* buffer=NULL; // Buffer to store the string
unsigned int size=0;
fp=popen(command,"r");
while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp))
    {
    size+=strlen(line);
    strcat(buffer=realloc(buffer,size),line);
    }

printf("Contents received from pipe\n ");
fputs(buffer,stdout);

free(buffer);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```